# Why have I stopped receiving weekly Screen Time notifications?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, screen-time

I used to receive weekly Screen Time notifications regarding my daily averages and such.  However, around a month ago, I randomly stopped receiving these notifications.

I've checked in the Notifications tab of the Settings app, and Screen Time notifications are turned on.  I tried a Google search to see if anyone else was experiencing this issue, but I could only find results about how to turn off Screen Time notifications rather than about not receiving them despite them being turned on.

Does anyone have any idea why I stopped getting these notifications?

(The device that I'm using is an iPhone SE running iOS 12.3.1, if that helps.  Also, my Screen Time settings are locked with a password that someone else knows, in case that makes any difference.)

Comment: Interesting - come to think of it, I don't recall getting any for a few weeks either. Will have to investigate!

Comment: I also haven't been getting these notifications, but after updating to ios 13 beta, they came back.

Comment: I received one yesterday after a long long time . I am on 12.3.1